# MTM : Is there a way to find test run completion status using command line utility tcm.exe

Tags: microsoft-test-manager, tcm

I use MTM (Microsoft test manager) for running my automated test cases.

I schedule test runs using `tcm /create` command (trigerred from a powershell script) and once the test run is completed I need to copy the `trx` (result) file on my local machine. So I want to wait till the test run is completed in some sort of polling mechanism.

Hence, I need a command to fetch the current test run status using test runid. Is there a way to get MTM test run status in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. The available switches for `run` option are:

- delete
- abort
- export
- list
- create
- publish

The only data you can take about `runs` using `/list` is

- Id
- Title
- Owner
- Date Completed

you can see this by running:

```
tcm run /list /planid:<plainId> /collection:<CollectionUrl> /teamproject:<TeamProject>
```

Moreover, you don't have the `runId` yet so even if there was an option to get the completion status, in your case that would not be easy.

So, I think you should start looking for another solution. Perhaps the [TFS Api](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb130146%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is what you need. 
Check these links:

1. [Automation test run creation using tfs api](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsmantest/thread/45d06e51-9cbe-4f3e-81c4-e5b8b955da7c/)
2. [TFS 2010 API - Get Results of a Test Run](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3279.tfs-2010-api-get-results-of-a-test-run.aspx)

Comment: I agree with @Schaliasos.
I needed the possibility to wait until a test run is complete some months ago and ended up implementing a command line tool using mentioned TFS Api.
It's working just perfect and you have a full control over it.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually get the test id - its what is printed out as a result of tcm.exe run /create command
in powershell it would be something like this:

```
$testRunSubmitResult = .$tcmPath run /create ......

$testID = $testRunSubmitResult -match "[0-9]{1,1000}"

(i excluded the error handling logic which needs to be present in order to verify that the run was submitted)

after that you can do the following thing - you can export the test run with the used id, and if the test didnt finish yet, you will get and error.

do

{

    Start-Sleep -s 60

    $testResults = .$tcmPath run /export /id:$testID /resultsfile:$args /collection ....

    if(Test-Path $args[0])

    {

        break

    }

    if($testResults.GetType() -eq @("1").GetType())

    {

        if($testResults[1].Contains("Completed export"))

        {

            break

        }

    }

    if ($testResults.Contains("Completed export"))

    {

        break
    }
}
while ($True)
```

This is not perfect as it might fail in test runs with big attachments (such as ones produced by the Video data collector) but it might be a solution for some of you

Or alternatively from powerscript you can just use the TFS API like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",

                       "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",

                       "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

$tfs = [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client.TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory]::GetTeamProjectCollection("http://tfs:8080/tfs/Collection")
$tfs.EnsureAuthenticated()
$testManagementService = $tfs.GetService([Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client.ITestManagementService])
$testManagementTeamProject = $testManagementService.GetTeamProject('Project');

do
{
    Start-Sleep -s 60
    $testRun = $testManagementTeamProject.TestRuns.Find($testId);
    if($testRun.State -eq 'Completed')
    {
        break
    }
    if($testRun.State -eq 'NeedsInvestigation')
    {
        break
    }
    if($testRun.State -eq 'Aborted')
    {
        break
    }
}
```